# How to build Node.js app in MS Team app studio?

Tags: node.js

I am just a rookie in this field. How can I make a Node.js app on app studio in ms team. I have searched but did not get answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to know at least a little Javascript, and at least a little about how to write a NodeJS app with Javascript.

   If you don't, get a book and/or work through some tutorials.  For example (Google NodeJS tutorial):

   - https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlB_eWDSMt4
2. Next, download MS App Studio and work through a tutorial.  For example:

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio

'Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for reply but i already gone through this link. and as you see in this link it shows tutorial of import an existing app . i want working of creating a new app in nodejs msteam appstudio